# Update object from objectlist with next object key

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Using Javascipt and have lodash installed in my project.

My input is as follows:

```
const fields = {
  accountBalance: {
    id: 1,
    field: 'input',
  },
  totalTrades: {
    id: 2,
    field: 'input',
  },
  winRate: {
    id: 3,
    field: 'slider'
  },
  reward: {
    id: 4,
    field: 'input',
  },
  risk: {
    id: 5,
    field: 'slider',
  }
}
```

My output I would like to have:

```
const fields = {
  accountBalance: {
    id: 1,
    field: 'input',
    nextFieldFocus: 'totalTrades'
  },
  totalTrades: {
    id: 2,
    field: 'input',
    nextFieldFocus: 'reward'
  },
  winRate: {
    id: 3,
    field: 'slider'
  },
  reward: {
    id: 4,
    field: 'input',
    nextFieldFocus: 'accountBalance'
  },
  risk: {
    id: 5,
    field: 'slider',
  }
}
```

Each object the field value can be either 'input' or a 'slider'.
Each time it update the field value I call a function that update the fields (the expected output above).
Each field where a field is a input, update the nextFieldFocus with the next key of the objectlist where the field is a input. If it can't find it in the remaining order, start over at the start of the object list where the field is a input.

What I tried:

```
const fields = {
  accountBalance: {
    id: 1,
    field: 'input',
  },
  totalTrades: {
    id: 2,
    field: 'input',
  },
  winRate: {
    id: 3,
    field: 'slider'
  },
  reward: {
    id: 4,
    field: 'input',
  },
  risk: {
    id: 5,
    field: 'slider',
  }
}

const keys = Object.keys(fields);

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const currentKey = keys[i];
  if (fields[currentKey].field === 'input') {
    let nextKey = keys[i + 1];
    while (nextKey && fields[nextKey].field !== 'input') {
      nextKey = keys[++i % keys.length];
    }
    fields[currentKey].nextFieldFocus = nextKey;
  }
}

console.log(fields);
```

[image]

Problem I am facing is that if it can't find the next object where field is a input that the nextFieldFocus won't be filled. Ideal is that it start checking from the start but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const fields = {
  accountBalance: {
    id: 1,
    field: 'input',
  },
  totalTrades: {
    id: 2,
    field: 'input',
  },
  winRate: {
    id: 3,
    field: 'slider'
  },
  reward: {
    id: 4,
    field: 'input',
  },
  risk: {
    id: 5,
    field: 'slider',
  }
}

const keys = Object.keys(fields);

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const currentKey = keys[i];
  const currentObj = fields[currentKey]
  if (currentObj.field === 'input') {
    for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j += 1) {
      const nextKey = keys[(i + j + 1) % keys.length];
      const nextObj = fields[nextKey]
      if (nextObj.field !== 'input') continue
      currentObj.nextFieldFocus = nextKey;
      break
    }
  }
}

console.log(fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single iteration through the object. Just save the first `"input"` and the `previous` input object to 2 variables. Whenever an `"input"` field is reached, update the previous "input" with the current key. When the last key is being iterated, update the previous input with the `first` input key.

```js
const fields={accountBalance:{id:1,field:"input"},totalTrades:{id:2,field:"input"},winRate:{id:3,field:"slider"},reward:{id:4,field:"input"},risk:{id:5,field:"slider"}};

let firstInput, previous

for (const key in fields) {
  const current = fields[key]

  if (current.field == 'input') {
    if (previous) previous.nextFieldFocus = key
    else firstInput = key

    previous = current
  }
}

// last entry
if (previous) previous.nextFieldFocus = firstInput

console.log(fields)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const keys = Object.keys(fields);

keys.forEach((field, idx) => {
  if (fields[field].field !== 'input') return;

  fields[field].nextFieldFocus = keys[idx + 1];
})
```